# Foundation + Flexslider with Thumbnails not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, flexslider

I'm trying to build a gallery page use Flexslider in a site built with Foundation.  If I build the Flexslider on its own, it works fine, but when I incorporate it into a page with Foundation it stops working.  I can only get any of the images to load by adding in some extra CSS to force the initial image to load, but the thumbnails do not control which slide is shown (nor do they even show as a clickable element) and none of the navigation controls appear.  Everything related to both Foundation and Flexslider has been copied from a working example to avoid typing errors.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Out of the box Flexslider thumbs work fine... put it into a Foundation environment and they don't appear. All sliders not involving thumbs work fine.

Comment: There is an issue in the Git Repo of Foundation: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/869

May be you can get the people of Zurb to reopen it or at least answer your question there. =) Also, from what I could read there, it is related to the positioning of scripts.

Answer (score 2):

As a work around, I did the following...

I created thumbs with the code below:

```
<div class="flexslider-controls">
    <ol class="new-nav">

        <li>                        
            <div class="medium-3 columns">                          
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-thumb-1.jpg" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="medium-3 columns">                          
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-thumb-1.jpg" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="medium-3 columns">                          
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-thumb-2.jpg" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="medium-3 columns">                          
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-thumb-3.jpg" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </li>

    </ol>
</div>
```

Then using some jquery, as you click on each thumb, it will change the slider to the corresponding slide:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.new-nav li a',function(){          
        var index = $('.new-nav li a').index(this) + 1;
        $('.videos-slider').flexslider(index);
        return false;
    });
});
```